# Spring MVC finds JSP view but fails to render

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a simple Spring MVC Java Application structure:
Spring Version 5.2.3
I am using JSPs as views.  (Only have 2 at this point - so super simple).
index.jsp and index2.jsp

On index.jsp I am doing some authentication.
On index2.jsp - this is the view after user has been authenticated.

So index.jsp is rendering fine when I hit the URL in the browser.  I do some stuff and then I have a JQuery post call that calls up the Controller and passes it a few things.
Here's the AJAX POST call -

```
function validateLoginServerSide(eventObj) {
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "UIDSignature": eventObj.UIDSignature,
        "firstName": eventObj.profile.firstName
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cdc/validate',
        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            console.log('succes: ' + data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log('error: ' + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the Controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method=RequestMethod.POST,
    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public String validateAuthentication(
    @RequestBody CompanyBO signature, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("firstName", signature.getFirstName());
    return "index2"; // return internal application page
}
```

`index2` as previously mentioned is a JSP and is located in the following directory in my project:
`src/main/webapp`

Here's what I don't understand - notice in my post callback in the success function - I print out `data`.
Well, in the console of my browser I see the contents of my JSP (index2.jsp) perfectly formatted html and even that one binding that resolved to the firstName that I passed into that method, but the browser window itself is still on the original view, `index.jsp` - so the new jsp is not rendered to the browser window - but it is FOUND, binding resolved, and as you will see below in the logs FORWARDED.

I did some research and I noticed some posts saying that one needs to include this in their POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
```

The version is dependent on the version of Tomcat that you are running (so the blogs have stated) --- and the reason for this is because Spring MVC doesn't know how to render JSPs without help.  Made sense to me so I tried it - but this didn't work.  Still same result.

And finally just to prove I'm not crazy - here's some DEBUG statements from Tomcat (as promised):

```
22:56:00.676 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Read "application/json" to [CompanyBO(UIDSignature=1234567, firstName=Alex)]
22:56:00.702 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView - View name 'index2', model {org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.companyBO=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors, firstName=Alex}
22:56:00.702 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView - Forwarding to [/index2.jsp]
22:56:00.946 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 200 OK
22:56:06.014 [http-apr-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/company/resources/javascript/lib/bootstrap.bundle.js.map", parameters={}
22:56:06.072 [http-apr-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["/resources/"]
22:56:06.082 [http-apr-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/company/resources/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css.map", parameters={}
22:56:06.084 [http-apr-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["/resources/"]
22:56:06.186 [http-apr-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 200 OK
22:56:06.202 [http-apr-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 200 OK
```

**Million dollar question:  How is it that the view is found, returned but not rendered?**

Comment: You're mixing design models. If you want to return JSON, you don't use JSP.

Comment: No, I don't want to return JSON - I want to return HTML.

Comment: To an AJAX call?

Comment: Good point.  It seems that I should be using another mechanism to affect the view to change rather that use the AJAX call.  Rookie mistake.  What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-I small clarification to the above question - I'm reacting to an event on the client side (event listener) and my goal is change the view.  I thought that I could accomplish this by notifying the appropriate method in the Controller that would return the view.  It seems that by doing this via AJAX that the behavior I'm seeing above is correct.  Question then becomes - how do I call the Controller from the client side to affect that change?

Comment: If you really want a page replacement using an HTML response, just use a plain old classic form post. Note, however, that _none of what you've shown_ should be used in a production application, only for learning about how the plumbing works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213285/discussion-between-ivan-drago-and-chrylis-on-strike).